# Optimisation for large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, iteration

I have posted a code for review in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966720/optimising-iteration-and-substitution-over-large-dataset). Yet as per now it did not receive the correct respond which I assume is due to the lengthiness of the code. Here I shall cut it to the chase. Suppose we have the following lists:

```
t0=[('Albania','Angola','Germany','UK'),('UK','France','Italy'),('Austria','Bahamas','Brazil','Chile'),('Germany','UK'),('US')]
t1=[('Angola', 'UK'), ('Germany', 'UK'), ('UK', 'France'), ('UK', 'Italy'), ('France', 'Italy'), ('Austria', 'Bahamas')]
t2=[('Angola:UK'), ('Germany:UK'), ('UK:France'), ('UK:Italy'), ('France:Italy'), ('Austria:Bahamas')]
```

the aim is for each pair in `t1` we go through `t0` and if the pair is found we replace it with the corresponding `t3` element, we can do this using the following:

```
result = []
for v1, v2 in zip(t1, t2):
    out = []
    for i in t0:
        common = set(v1).intersection(i)
        if set(v1) == common:
            out.append(tuple(list(set(i) - common) + [v2]))
        else:
            out.append(tuple(i))
    result.append(out)

pprint(result, width=100)
```

which gives:

```
[[('Albania', 'Germany', 'Angola:UK'),
  ('UK', 'France', 'Italy'),
  ('Austria', 'Bahamas', 'Brazil', 'Chile'),
  ('Germany', 'UK'),
  ('U', 'S')],
 [('Albania', 'Angola', 'Germany:UK'),
  ('UK', 'France', 'Italy'),
  ('Austria', 'Bahamas', 'Brazil', 'Chile'),
  ('Germany:UK',),
  ('U', 'S')],
 [('Albania', 'Angola', 'Germany', 'UK'),
  ('Italy', 'UK:France'),
  ('Austria', 'Bahamas', 'Brazil', 'Chile'),
  ('Germany', 'UK'),
  ('U', 'S')],
 [('Albania', 'Angola', 'Germany', 'UK'),
  ('France', 'UK:Italy'),
  ('Austria', 'Bahamas', 'Brazil', 'Chile'),
  ('Germany', 'UK'),
  ('U', 'S')],
 [('Albania', 'Angola', 'Germany', 'UK'),
  ('UK', 'France:Italy'),
  ('Austria', 'Bahamas', 'Brazil', 'Chile'),
  ('Germany', 'UK'),
  ('U', 'S')],
 [('Albania', 'Angola', 'Germany', 'UK'),
  ('UK', 'France', 'Italy'),
  ('Brazil', 'Chile', 'Austria:Bahamas'),
  ('Germany', 'UK'),
  ('U', 'S')]]
```

This list has length of 6 which shows that there are 6 elements in `t1` and `t2` and each sublist has 5 elements which are corresponding to number of elements in `t0`. As it stands the code is fast yet in my case I have `t0` which has length of ~48000 and t1 with length of ~30000. Running time takes almost forever I wonder how one performs same operations with faster methods?

Comment: why this `('U', 'S')],`?

Comment: Good point, I am trying to figure this out myself :/

Comment: Your last tuple should be like so: `('US',)`. The reason is that `('US')=='US` (both strings) but ('US')!=('US',) - as the last one is a tuple with one element in.

Comment: Why have `t2`?  Can't it be easily derived from `t1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a double list comprehension. The code runs approximately 3.47 times faster (13.3 µs vs 46.2 µs).

```
t0=[('Albania','Angola','Germany','UK'),('UK','France','Italy'),('Austria','Bahamas','Brazil','Chile'),('Germany','UK'),('US')]
t1=[('Angola', 'UK'), ('Germany', 'UK'), ('UK', 'France'), ('UK', 'Italy'), ('France', 'Italy'), ('Austria', 'Bahamas')]
t2=[('Angola:UK'), ('Germany:UK'), ('UK:France'), ('UK:Italy'), ('France:Italy'), ('Austria:Bahamas')]

# We transform the lists of tuple to lists of sets for easier and faster computations
# We transform the lists of tuple to lists of sets for easier and faster computations
t0 = [set(x) for x in t0]
t1 = [set(x) for x in t1]

# We define a function that removes list of elements and adds an element
# from a set 
def add_remove(set_, to_remove, to_add):
    result_temp = set_.copy()
    for element in to_remove:
        result_temp.remove(element)
    result_temp.add(to_add)
    return result_temp

# We do the computation using a double list comprehension
result = [[add_remove(y, x, z) if x.issubset(y) else y for y in t0] 
          for x, z in zip(t1, t2)]
```

Comment: Thanks but then there is an issue take `result[:1]` you get `[[{'Albania', 'Angola:UK', 'Germany'},
  {'Italy', 'UK:France'},
  {'Austria:Bahamas', 'Brazil', 'Chile'},
  {'Germany:UK'},
  {'S', 'U'}]]` which is wrong each time one pair should be taken not all possible. Look at the out put of mine in the question.

Comment: Since we were working with sets there is no order. That is why the output wasn't in the right order. I changed it to lists to have your expected outcome, but it will be a bit slower

Comment: So now when I copy your answer it throws error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: `list.copy()` was [implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) in python 3.3. If you have an older version you should change the line `result_temp = list_.copy()` by `result_temp = list(list_)`

Comment: Thank you I'm gonna wait a little longer for more participation and if there won't be any faster method, I'll accept yours - it is indeed way faster than what I had but still it will take around 250mins to go through my original data that I'm handling and I would need to rerun it so I think I still need to go more down in minutes.

Comment: @William no problem for the wait. Anyways, I think I managed to make the sets work, it's three times faster than my other method. Feel free to check my edited answer

Comment: I checked it on sample of my dataset - went faster by a few seconds indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196368/discussion-between-vlemaistre-and-william).